# How to splay a column of type dictionary

Tags: kdb

I have a column in my table whose values that are dictionaries. The type in the meta of that column is " ".

I want to know how to splay this table. When I try to splay it, I get a type error. I am aware only vectors can be splayed, however, I have seen a table where a column holds dictionaries splayed before, so I know it's possible, but I am not sure how it is done.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are only supported in kdb version >3.6.

If you are running 3.6/4.0, double check you are enumerating the table for splay.

```
`:path/to/table set .Q.en[`:hdb;table]
```

If <3.6 json string is a good alternative although not recommended on large tables as `.j.k` is slow.

Comment: Alright, that's good to know since I am not on 3.6 yet. However, I have seen it done on <3.5.

Comment: example was probably a flat file